# mod_rewrite error 404 if .php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I rewrite my urls to be user friendly. For example I have a page called user.php that I rewrite to /user. But a user can still use user.php. Can I redirect to a 404 if they request a page with a .php extension?

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)$ user.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\ /?].*HTTP/
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: that works but i can still access the page if i add a question mark after user.php?. maybe i can do something about that to?

Comment: R=404 is allowed, however apache only sends the `Location` header is the http-code is in the 300 range.

Comment: you should add [nc], otherwise pages will load with uppercase extensions

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, I think:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ path/to/your/404file [L]
```

Comment: so i need to add rule for all my pages?

Answer (score 2):

A [301 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) *may* be more appropriate for this task.