# htaccess - remove "index.php" from URL and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

At my website, I was using URL addresses such as

```
http://me.example.com/index.php?p=home
```

Then I decided to use

```
http://me.example.com/?p=home
```

It all worked automatically without any ".htaccess" file. But addresses which contain "index.php" also still work. Some sites have links to my site in "old" format. I want people to stop using this "old" format and redirect them to the "new" format URL, whenever they use "old" format. All I want to do is to remove "index.php" from URL and also change this URL in visitor's browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764828/htaccess-redirect-to-remove-index-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code that will go in .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: how would one preserve an url path and still do this? eg example.com/folder/index.php => example.com/foler/

Comment: figured it out: RewriteRule ^(.*)?index\.php/?$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]