# Removing "index.php?" from http://domain.com/index.php?controller/action

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have created an application in PHP MVC,and the http request was like 
**domain.com/index.php?controller/action**, i want to remove **index.php?** and the final url looks like http://domain.com/controller/action.
Any help will be highly appreciated

currently my .htaccess file looks like below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

it only removes the index.php and the url become http://domain.com/?controller/action,
i want that "?" to be off from the url.

Comment: Possible dupicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url & many more.

Comment: research before asking questions

Comment: but it does not remove the "?" symbol, i want to remove index.php along with "?". i tried this one : ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] but shows error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `mod_rewire` module to get the job done. What you are asking is SEO friendly URLs. If you search search a bit you will find a lot of examples.

put this in your root .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! I tried it, but it only removes the index.php and the url become http://domain.com/?controller/action, i want that "?" to be off from the url.