# Redirect index.php to root, and www to non www with rewrite_mod

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

someone knows how can i redirect in the .htaccess this rules bellow ?

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php to http://domain.com
```

and

```
http://www.domain.com to http://domain.com
```

many tanks

Comment: did not found http://www.domain.com/index.php to http://domain.com... only www to non www, i would like to have this both in only one rule... can you help-me with that Cheesemacfly ? tanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since I'm guessing `index.php` is what gets served when you go to your document root, you want to explicitly check that `/index.php` is what is being **requested**, and not part of the URI, which it will be once the URL-file mapping pipeline does its thing.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]
```

Then the www to non-www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: why there is space after {3,9}\ /

Comment: @ShreenivasChikati because that's what the first line of the request looks like, e.g.: `GET /index.php HTTP/1.1`