# Remove index.php in joomla

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, joomla2.5

Hi I want to remove the index.php in my url. I tried alot of methods but none of them work. All of them reponse 500 error or could not find folder. any one can help me please. I just use normal joomla page dont have any thing special but removing index.php seem impossible to me

This is link to my website `http://www.website.com/index.php/vn/`
I am using joomla 2.5

Hi i fixed it. on some sever we have to do a little modified to the htaccess not just remove .txt and add . in front of it.

In my case, I need to add . in to the line "RewriteBase /" => "RewriteBase /."

Comment: can you show us anything you have tried?

Comment: You can't remove the `index.php` for a Joomla site. It is required for the site to run. I'm not sure as to why you want to remove it to be honest

Comment: Have you tried to edit your SEO settings at Joomla configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on some sever we have to do a little modified to the htaccess not just remove .txt and add . in front of it.

In my case, I need to add . in to the line "RewriteBase /" => "RewriteBase /."

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is an option to turn on search engine friendly URLs.  To completely get rid of "index.php" you need to be running Joomla on Apache server.

1. Rename "htaccess.txt" file in your root Joomla directory to ".htaccess".
2. Site > Global Configuration > Site > SEO Settings  and set these settings:

Search Engine Friendly URLs    -    Yes
Use URL rewriting    -    Yes
Adds Suffix to URL    -    No
Unicode Aliases    -    No

Comment: Only the first two options are needed. The others: "Yes Adds Suffix to URL - No" and "Unicode Aliases - No" won't have effect on making index.php appearing or not appearing.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url for further explanation and locate the line commencing with "RewriteEngine On" in your joomla_root/.htaccess file - hope it helps, Gez