# .htaccess index.php url redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have got url like this:

> http://www.example.com/index.php/shop/productname

or like this

> http://www.example.com/index.php/productname

How Can i redirect all this pages to own, but without index.php?

I want to see

> http://www.example.com/shop/productname and http://www.example.com/productname

Comment: Are you using some CMS framework here like Magento?

Comment: Take a look at this <a href="http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F">resource</a>. It has everything you need.

Comment: See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:
`RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]`