# Jquery Ajax Link to folder with parameters doesnt work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I just transferred my site over to a new server and I am encountering a problem.

Previously, the following would work:

```
var ajaxURL = 'http://www.example.com/cart/?parameter=1';
ajaxCaptureRequest = $.post( ajaxURL, { cart_action: "capture", firstName: $('#firstName').val(),  totalSub: $('#totalSub').val() }, function(data){});
```

Now on my new server it doesn't work. If however, I change the ajaxURL to:

```
var ajaxURL = 'http://www.example.com/cart/index.php?parameter=1';
```

it works.

For stupid reasons I cant change the code permanently like this so it has to be without the 'index.php' in the ajaxURL variable.

What settings do I need to change in order to get this done?

Comment: why are you sending two `cart_action` to the php? and are you using somekind of php MVC framework?

Comment: That was a mistake. I changed my real code to make the example more concise. I have corrected that now though. You can assume the parameter is not redundant. 
No framework is being used.

Comment: if there is no framework at your site then how the url should know about sending the query string to which file? In short there is no way of doing it.

Comment: well is it `input_type=ajax` or `cart_action=ajax`? You should check to see where your requests are landing

Comment: I am sorry I made a mistake with the code, so I cleaned up the example code again. My apologies.

Comment: This code was working on my previous server, just when I switched over it stopped working. There must be some kind of server setting to change so that it works. I assumed it works as index.php is the directory index. Just like if you go to www.example.com/cart it will take you to www.example.com/cart/index.php (assuming it exists), so too, index.php will be the assumed destination in this case. That was how I presumed it was working till now.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using anyframeworks or whatever you could remove the occurance of index.php as mention in the periovus stackoverflow answers

URL :: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4365161/4119740

you could write the following lines in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Hope This Solves your problem