# how to stop site showing index.php in the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, https, redirect

My site is resolving with both:

https://www.itcontractorsuk.com AND https://www.itcontractorsuk.com/index.php

What can I do so that the extra index.php doesn't show up in the URL. It's only happening with homepage.

Comment: Maybe this is what you looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url

Comment: Did it work for your case?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]
```

Should do the trick.

Put this in your .htaccess

Comment: This does do the redirect. Isn't there an alternate to the above solution. Inner pages are working fine without the above code. I wanted some solution for homepage.

Comment: This is the only clean way of doing it AFAIK.