# how to make pretty url in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

I am new in laravel I am just try to remove index.php in each route such as https://localhost/test/public/index.php/test1 into https://localhost/test/public/test1.
I can used mod_rewrite code to solve this issue but does not work.
My code in .htaccess file which can be inside public folder is as follow:-

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It shows error

```
The requested URL /test/public/test1 was not found on this server
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess remove index.php from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mishanon but it also not working.

Comment: Do you install mod_rewrite?

Comment: yes I can enable mod_rewite. 
My operating system is Ubuntu 16.04.