# How facebook like websites is able to load the profile, instead of a directory when a request like facebook.com/profile/username is recieved?

Tags: facebook, web, get, request

When the facebook.com/profile/{username} is requested how is server able to load page with data corresponding to that user, instead of navigating to a directory named in that {username}, and possibly showing a 404 error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's achieved typically using a pattern called "front controller", where all requests are handled by the same file (let's say `index.php`, talking specifically about PHP now). So all URLs are like this:

```
facebook.com/index.php/profile/abc
facebook.com/index.php/account
```

That file serves as the bootstrap for the application, reading extra parameters (anything after `index.php`) and dispatching requests to the appropriate handlers/controllers.

Then there's multiple ways you can get rid of that ugly `index.php`, depending on how you configure your web server (loads of questions here about that subject: [htaccess remove index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url) as an example).

Read more about it here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller