# Htaccess index file, if exists

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I would need such a .htaccess file, which enables me direct access to some files by extension (images), and in any other case it checks if entryPoint2.php exists, if does, execute that file, if not, executes entryPont.php. This is what I made so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.ico|\.flv|\.mpeg|\.mp4|\.mp3|\.swf)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/downloads
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/entryPoint2.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ entryPoint2.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ entryPoint.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ http://www.example.com [R,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=301]
<Files .htaccess>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Files>
```

images works, but I get "forbidden" error, it looks for index.php

Comment: use the copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url

Comment: If I understand correctly, other than those files with the specified extensions, you want to serve either entryPoint.php or entryPoint2.php based on the existence of entryPoint2.php, without redirecting. Is that correct?

Comment: yes "11 more to go"

Comment: Then, the link provided by @Jagadeesh doesn't help, because it is all about redirecting. I'll post an answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement turns out to be less complex than I initially thought.
What you need is a white list and a simple file check.

This should do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|bmp|ico|flv|mpeg|mp4|mp3|swf)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/entryPoint2.php -f
RewriteRule ^ entryPoint2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ entryPoint.php
```

Line by line explanation:

- Line 1 is self-explanatory.
- Line 2 is an extension-based while list.
  It makes Apache serve files matching those extensions immediately, ignoring the rest of the .htaccess.
- Line 3 checks the existence of `entryPoint2.php`.
  If, for instance, `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is `/foo/bar`, it checks if `/foo/bar/entryPoint2.php` exists.
- Line 4 will serve `entryPoint2.php` if line 3 evaluates to true, ignoring the rest of the .htaccess.
- Line 5 serves `entryPoint.php` for any other case.

There you go.