# redirecting visitor using htaccess or php or anything

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Is there a way to direct a visitor using `.htaccess` from directories like

```
http://domain.com/afolder/bfolder/index.php
```

to

```
http://domain.com/afolder/bfolder/
```

I want to redirect visitor from first link to second one to hide `index.php`.

I have tried this on `.htaccess` with no success

```
Redirect 302 /afolder/bfolder/index.php /afolder/bfolder/
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Please refer here and search first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't want to use a 302, you want search engines to consider the /.../ location as the only one, otherwise you end up with duplicate content issues. 302 is a temporary redirect, 301 is permanent.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.(html|php)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/%1 [R=301,L]
```

This assumes, as in your case, http. not https, if that's not correct, change http to https.

This handles everything on the site, including things like:

`/index.html` or `/index.php` which are both rewritten to `/`

Comment: i have fixed his dear but thanks for your answer. and i have another issue here can you please help me with it ? i would really appreciate it . here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283583/right-format-of-php-breadcrumb-code

Comment: that question has no connection to this question, I'm sure someone will help there.

Comment: yes it is not, but i needed help in that maybe you have knowledge in php

Comment: lol, we all need help with things, but some of us also get paid to deal with problems, that is, it's our job. Which means we don't have limitless free time to help others for free. Providing help here is something we chose to do, when it's convenient, or we know the answer, or it's an interesting problem.