# right format of php breadcrumb code

Tags: php

i need help with myy php breadcrumb

using the code below i get breadcrumb like this on output

```
<a href="http://domain.com">Home</a> &raquo; <a href="//Folder/">Folder</a> &raquo; <a href="//Folder/Folder/"></a> Live TV </div>
```

the problem is i get // on some parts

here's my code. hope you get it and help me with it

```
<?php
    $file = basename("/".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

    $filename = (count(explode('.', $file)) === 1 ? $file : implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $file), 0, (count(explode('.', $file))-1))));
    $Pages = array(
        'folder' => 'Folder',
        $filename => 'Folder'
    );

    $path = "/".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    $parts = explode('/',$path);
    if (count($parts) < 2)
    {
    echo("home");
    }
    else
    {
    echo ("<a href=\"http://domain.com\">Home</a>  ");
    $cnt = count($parts);
    for ($i = 2; $i < $cnt; $i++)
        {
        if (!strstr($parts[$i],"."))
            {
            echo("&raquo; <a href=\"");
            for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {echo $parts[$j]."/";};
            echo("\">". str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]])."</a> ");
            }
        else
            {
            $str = $parts[$i];
            $pos = strrpos($str,".");
            $parts[$i] = substr($str, 0, $pos);
            echo str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]]);
            };
        };
    };  
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the output of `$parts` after your explode().
Could it be that there are some empty arrays?
If yes, then

```
for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {echo $parts[$j]."/";};
```

would output a single `/` before entering another loop.

Comment: i have removed `/` from here `for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {echo $parts[$j]."/";};` but the output becomes like this `<a href="http://domain.com">Home</a> &raquo; <a href="folder">Foldera</a> &raquo; <a href="folderfolder"></a> Folderb </div>` it should become like this `<a href="http://domain.com">Home</a> &raquo; <a href="folder">Foldera</a> &raquo; <a href="folder/folder"></a> Folderb </div>`

Comment: You can't remove `/` from the loop but maybe start with `$j = 1` if `$parts[$j]` is empty.

Comment: i idn't know about that small problem :D i changed it to `$j = 1' it worked. thanks a lot and for your ard work

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)