# Change HTML link to another link

Tags: php, html

I have a page where to open the home site the link would look like this:
`www.pagename.at/index.php?page=home`. i would like if the user inputs `www.pagename.at/home` that it would redirect it to the right page.

EDIT:
based on Kiran Shetty's answer i found this link:
[url rewriting for beginners](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Comment: refer link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use url rewriting technique's. you can make it easily by using php frameworks. otherwise you have to use rewrite techniques to achiew that stuff.