# The redirection rule to the home page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, web

What rule should I write in the .htaccess file for the redirect to work from http://site.ru/index.php/ru - to http://site.ru/ru/?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess remove index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index.php/ru  http://site.ru/ru/ [R=301,L]

Comment: No problem, anytime!

Answer (score 0):

Enable rewrite module in apache, then add below lines to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

OR

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: edited rule, you have to enable rewrite module in apache

Comment: rewrite module is enable, but this rule not working too

Comment: have you restarted apache?