# .htaccess editing to hide folder from url & accessing main domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i used a .htaccess editing to hide folder/directory from my website url. 
`skynetbd.net/user_profile/login.php` to `skynetbd.net/login.php`

I used this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Turn mod_rewrite on RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+user_profile/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^user_profile/)^(.*)$ /user_profile/$1 [L,NC]
```

And it worked fine for my purpose ..but unfortunately i could not access using this domain "skynetbd.net" anymore but "skynetbd.net/index.php"  !!! The server was showing:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /user_profile/ on this server.
>   Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Please help on this case..i must access in my website using only "skynetbd.net".

Comment: When writing a question, only bold text that needs emphasis, not all the text.

Comment: Thanks.It was my first time.

Comment: anyone ?? please help...

Comment: instead of bending you to make it work, try adding this too,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url
will allow you to remove the .index.php automatically

Comment: actually i don't want to remove index.php ..i want to remove user_profile folder from the url. But when i edit with that the domain can not reach to index.php directly & shows the error. That's the problem.