# Rewrite main domain to a page with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i did a .htaccess edit to add index.php after my domain as: [skynetbd.net/index.php][1].

---

**i used:**

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?skynetbd\.net
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
 Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

But unfortunately all of my links redirects to skynetbd.net/index.php like a loop !! please give a solution to prevent this problem..

Comment: forgive me but I do not understand the problem, I was also on the site but I do not see anything unusual, could you explain it better?

Comment: actually i removed the code for now.  problem is ..when i am using it ..all of my links like skynetbd.net/service.php  skynetbd.net/contact.php are redirecting to index.php page !! i also used there:

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /user_profile/([^.]+)\.php [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,NC,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/user_profile/$1\.php -f [NC]
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ user_profile/$1.php [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: or can you please solve the problem for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48657691/htaccess-editing-to-hide-folder-from-url-accessing-main-domain

Comment: Which code are you currently using in your htaccess the code you posted above in the question body or the code you posted in comments?

Comment: i am using the code of my comment currently to hide a folder from the url. please have a look.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48657691/htaccess-editing-to-hide-folder-from-url-accessing-main-domain