# Remove index.php using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to remove index.php from url using htaccess.
Code Example:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

For example : If my url https://url.com/index.php then how to make it https://url.com ?.

And the 2nd question is, if someone types https://url.com/directory which is contained non-index, then how to redirect them to the main domain without `index.php` ?

I am using simple single index file at root not a framework. and using cloudflare dns.

When i replaced last line with `RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]` then working.

For example : `https://url.com/demo` or `https://url.com/demo/demo1` (not exists directory) then it redirect to `https://url.com` without `index.php`.

But when the url is `https://url.com/index.php` , it still showing the same url `https://url.com/index.php` . How to remove `index.php`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess remove index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url)

Comment: Not worked for me.

Comment: @Hiptop are you using any framework?

Comment: No simple one page index file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggest. But i just edited your code, which is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your project root please create or put .htaccess file. And add following lines.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: check rewrite module is enabled?

Comment: Yes rewrite module enabled.

Comment: .htaccess and index.php is in same path?

Comment: Yes in same path.

Comment: it may be issue in your local server, check in live server

Comment: then local rewrite module is enable, ask server team to enable rewrite module globally

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Projectname
# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: deploy  on server it will work. may be in local not work, which one you using xamp or wamp ?

Comment: do you remove index.php from config file ?  $config['index_page'] = '';   $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

Comment: Change in config file as upper comment.   all the best, i m sure it will work

Answer (score 0):

if Use CodeIgniter

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ProjectName/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Else

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the basic rule to hide index.php from the URL. Put this in your root .htaccess file.

mod_rewrite must be enabled with PHP and this will work for the PHP version higher than 5.2.6.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

```
# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```