# VirtualHost port 8080. apache 2.4 . removing index.php in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This is my Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.localhost:8080
   DocumentRoot "D:/test/testpage/"
   ServerName testpage
   ServerAlias testpage.localhost
   ErrorLog "logs/testpage-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/testpage-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

system/host

```
 127.0.0.1  testpage.localhost
```

httpd.conf in xampp/apache/conf/

```
Listen 8080
ServerName localhost:8080

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<Directory />
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

my .htaccess file inside testpage folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and in my application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://testpage.localhost:8080';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

the only issue am facing is that index.php, i can access my other pages but it have index.php between base_url() and view.

Comment: place your .htaccess file in project folder not inside application folder

Comment: my .htaccess is in the same level of application folder and not inside of application folder.

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying the following VirtualHost (vhost) directives.

It defines `D:/test/testpage/testpage` as the pubic root of the site. Both `.htaccess` and CodeIgniter's `index.php` should be in this directory.
I've removed the `ServerAlias` - you don't need it.
I've added explicit directives for the vhost directory

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.localhost:8080
   DocumentRoot D:/test/testpage
   ServerName testpage
   ErrorLog "logs/testpage-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/testpage-access.log" common

   <Directory D:/test/testpage>
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

system/host should be

```
127.0.0.1  testpage
```

Because you have named the virtual host "testpage" the following should work.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://testpage/';
```

Comment: Thanks for giving a solution, i've just want to remove the index.php and i've read an htaccess tutorial http://phptutorialandscripts.blogspot.com/2013/03/htaccess-file-tutorial.html in the BASICS  and it solved my problem(last two words of the first paragraph).