# removing index.php from site in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Whenever I try logging into my site with a wrong user details, I get redirected from `www.example.com/` to `www.example.com/index.php`.

I would like to remove `index.php` from my link.

Here is the content of my `htaccess` file, which does not work for me.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^login index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url

Comment: By default it redirects to site url.

Comment: yes @GufranHasan

Comment: What do you mean by ` wrong user details`?

Comment: Whenever i try logging into my site with wrong user name and password, `index.php` is been added to my url that is, making it `www.example.com/index.php`. i want to get rid of `index.php` so that users can't even add it to my url

Answer (score 0):

Check if this can work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: same with first answer

Answer (score 0):

Check `mod_rewrite` module is enabled if not you first enable it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url)

[htaccess documrntation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

Comment: This code takes me to my XAMPP dashboard. doesn't work

Comment: see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url

Comment: Still the same thing