# how to remove index.php from the url in wordpress running on compute engine

Tags: wordpress, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I have a vm running wordpress on compute engine and the only way to access the api is mysite/index.php/wp-json.  I believe this is causing things to break because I can not upload photos / posts.  How can I remove the need for index.php?

Comment: seems to be apache or nginx configuration... have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url

Answer (score 0):

Procedure to login to your Google Compute engine VM instance can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance)