# Redirecting to index.php but not showing 'index.php' in search bar

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have used a simple

```
<a href="/index.php">link</a>
```

to try and redirect to my index/home page, but in the search bar it shows ..../index.php. I want to know a way to redirect to the page without the index.php showing in the search bar.

Comment: Redirect to root with "/". Also remove .php from your urls with your .htaccess file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess remove index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rewrite in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```