# phpmyadmin is not loading correctly

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin

i tried to login to my phpmyadmin (EC2 instance) i tried to visit

`domain.com/phpmyadmin` it didn't load then I typed `domain.com/phpmyadmin/index.php` it loads. After logging in I am seeing total mess of my phpmyadmin

[image]

What could be the reason for it? Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It can't load the icons. The icons don't exist or the path is wrong.

Comment: The path is correct. one question why it's not accessible via domain.com/phpmyadmin? I have to use `domain.com/phpmyadmin/index.php` to access. Any reason?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url

Comment: Oh i know this httacess @AndreiLupuleasa. If path is wrong then I shouldn't be able to access phpmyadmin or be able to login. but I was able to login. so seems path is correct.

Comment: Have you got something in the Apache configuration (or possibly `.htaccess`) that's disabling directory indexes? That would at least explain why you need to type `index.php`

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa answer from this linked questions solved my problem. you can add it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

[htaccess remove index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url)

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to RewriteRule of .htaccess file.
Please check .htaccess file and remove RewriteRule .*.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]