# How can i fix a problem with URL Routes in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel `routes`, and I have a problem with URL

for example

`https://laracasts.com/discuss`. - URL has a double
`https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss`

how to fix it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYBOw.png)

Comment: Please share your `public/.htaccess` file's content

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't already there, create an .htaccess file in the Laravel root directory. Create a .htaccess file your Laravel root directory if it does not exists already. (Normally it is under your public_html folder)

Now you should be able to access the website without the "/public/index.php/" part.

Edit the .htaccess file so that it contains the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't like this solution. this implies that your web server's document root corresponds to your base path which can be very dangerous in terms of security

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url

Comment: I have .htaccess like laravel repository. So i havent problem with DocumentRoot. I have a problem with URL. 

I think its decision on for me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url