# Removing php extension and index (.htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I achieved to remove php extension by using htaccess. My codes are

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


www.abc.com/folder1/page.php -> www.abc.com/folder1/page
```

Of course that code removed php extension for index.php

```
www.abc.com/folder1/index.php -> www.abc.com/folder1/index
```

My question is how can I remove the word index

```
www.abc.com/folder1/index -> www.abc.com/folder1/
```

**Briefly, when I type www.abc.com/folder1/page, page.php should run in folder1 and when I type www.abc.com/folder1/ index.php should run in folder1.**

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4365161/3241041

Comment: It removed index.php but other pages have error 404

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess remove index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url)

Comment: Nope, not same. It just removes index.php. I want to remove php extension for all pages and remove index.

Comment: _“and when I type www.abc.com/folder1/ index.php should run in folder1”_ - that should happen automatically, if you specify `DirectoryIndex` accordingly …

Answer (score 1):

You may replace your shown rule with these 2 rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file and remove index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index|(\S+?))\.php[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. It removde index (www.abc.com/folder1/index.php turns into www.abc.com/folder1/) but other pages have error 404 (www.abc.com/folder1/page.php should've turned into www.abc.com/folder1/page but got error 404)

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code. On my localhost http://localhost/example/index.php is redirected to http://localhost/example/ it's OK but when I type http://localhost/example/folder1/page it's not redirected to http://localhost/example/folder1/page.php I got error 404 Object not found.