# Forcing HTTP to HTTPS changes in URL structure with .htaccess

Tags: https

Without SSL and without forcing the HTTPS, my urls look like these:
(1) redbrickoffices.com/home
(2) redbrickoffices.com/mainplan

```
================================================
This code was already present.

#php_flag display_errors on
#php_value error_reporting 9999


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


================================================
I added this code with the above code to force http to https

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} redbrickoffices\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://redbrickoffices.com/$1 [R,L]
================================================
```

But after forcing the http to https, my urls change to
https://redbrickoffices.com/index.php?url=mainplan

I should be getting https://redbrickoffices.com/mainplan

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url

Comment: It did not. :( Editing the .htaccess file is greek and latin for me...

Comment: Maybe this can help more : https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/

Comment: nope :( I don't understand it much