# laravel API routs return 404 error in 000webhost

Tags: php, laravel

after deploying my laravel project to 000webhost I got 404 error with every routing but the main page is working ex

> : https://dalelalbab.000webhostapp.com/

no problems but when I try

> https://dalelalbab.000webhostapp.com/api/class

it returns with 404 .
my `.htaccess`

```
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
  </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php`
</IfModule>
```

my `index.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));


if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}


require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';



$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

my `.env` like:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:4QdCynEnxFwGy+a0VE8C6gYqg0rL0iL9TAKV5SVw24E=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://dalelalbab.000webhostapp.com/

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=id17195231_dalelalbab
DB_USERNAME=id17195231_lubna
DB_PASSWORD=d************
```

Comment: https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/how-to-make-mod-rewrite-rules-working-14

Comment: @user3532758 I have try it and put .htaccess in the root but nothing changed

Comment: you shouldn't need to move httaccess file. Just add this line `RewriteBase /` at the top of the htaccess file.

Comment: Also remove your passwords from here, and change your passwords on the server.

Comment: @user3532758 I didn't move it I just copy it to the root. in all cases nothing has changed

Comment: Then you need to make sure that rewrite is enabled. Coz it's a rewrite issue for sure. https://dalelalbab.000webhostapp.com/index.php/api/class

Comment: @user3532758 oh thank you very much but why do I need to include the index file?

Comment: I was just showing you that it is a rewrite issue, that index.php file is not being rewritten.

Comment: @user3532758 thank you for the explanation I will look for this issue

Comment: the solve of rewrite problem was found in this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url)