# Replace substring in URL via RewriteEngine

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

im desperately trying to make RewriteEngine to rewrite the following pattern:

```
https://example.com/api/model/id/
https://example.com/staging/api/model/id/
```

**internally** to

```
https://example.com/index.php/model/id/
https://example.com/staging/index.php/model/id/
```

I already tried several suggestions from several boards but none of them worked out for me. **Ideally the rule should just search for "/api/" and replace it with "/index.php/".** I can't figure out, why it is so hard to make that work, my other rules worked out fine till now...

Here is my last try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/api/(.+)$ $1/index.php/$2 [R=301,L]
# RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.+)/api/(.+)$ http://localhost/dev/someFolder/index.php/$2 [R=301,L]
```

What am I making wrong? I'm just telling the rule to make ($1)/api/($2) to ($1)/index.php/($2), that shouldn't be that hard. Ideally the rule also shouldn't care about whats standing before the "/api/" pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around, which seems to work out fine in most use-cases:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Found the answer here: [htaccess remove index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url)

**Just keep in mind, that you have to put your files in a subdir named after the string you want to replace "index.php" with (e.g. to replace /index.php/$1 with /api/$1 you have to put all your files into a subdir named api).**

This is just perfectly fine for my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

something like this...

```
RewriteEngine On
                
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^staging/api/(.*)$ /staging/index.php/$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, worked also out after changing /index.php/$1 to ./index.php/$1.