# Rewrite Rule keep showing Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying rewrite rule and has been stuck for so long.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page\=about$
RewriteRule ^$ /about? [L]
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

From

```
https://localhost/site/
https://localhost/site/?page=about
https://localhost/site/?page=food
https://localhost/site/?page=place
https://localhost/site/?page=shop
https://localhost/site/?page=place&area=west
```

To

```
https://localhost/site/
https://localhost/site/about
https://localhost/site/food
https://localhost/site/place
https://localhost/site/shop
https://localhost/site/place/west
```

Whenever I try on my localhost or my domain (top level domain: [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)), I keep getting :
**`Internal Server Error`**

---

Edit:
Now I have the following code. There's no error.

```
RewriteEngine on
#1) redirect the client from "/index.php/foo/bar" to "/foo/bar"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R]
#2)internally map "/foo/bar" to "/index.php/foo/bar"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=/$1 [L]
```

No error but if I were to go to
https://localhost/site/about
It will redirect me to homepage content even though the URL is https://localhost/site/about

But on live site, [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com), it works almost perfectly.

```
www.mysite.com/about √ works
www.mysite.com/shop √ works
www.mysite.com/place/west x not working
```

Since I copy this from another source, the comment said that #2)internally map "/foo/bar" to "/index.php/foo/bar".

-How do I make this map to index.php?page=about?

-How do I make it work for [www.mysite.com/place/west](http://www.mysite.com/place/west)?

Comment: What does the error log have to say about this?

Comment: And where is your .htaccess located?

Comment: Error log says  [pid 4448] [client ::1:55666] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: It is located at localhost/site/.htaccess

Comment: Probably because only made an internal rewrite, not an external redirect. Add the `R` flag to your rule (for testing, `R=302` is recommended, you can change it to `301` later on when everything works.)

Comment: What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? This alone won't cause the rewrite-loop (Internal Server Error) you describe (although it's not correct either). You would need other directives for this to work. Where is this `.htaccess` file located? As written, it is not interchangeable between a subdirectory and the document root.

Comment: thats all i have. i am new to this .htaccess

Comment: Edited : I managed to get it to work a bit, but I am still stuck with /place/area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule :

```
 RewriteEngine On
 #Redirect /site/?page=foobar to /site/foobar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /site/(?:index\.php)?\?page=(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /site/%1? [L,R]
# Internally rewrite new path to the original one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:site/)?(.+)/?$ /site/?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I haven't tested it but I believe it should work for your URLs.

Comment: OMG. This is almost right. However, I am unable to get this part to work.

Comment: this part: From https://localhost/site/?page=place&place=west to https://localhost/site/place/west

Comment: @OneNation Glad it was helpful.  For the second part to work, you will need to write a new rule that can accept query strings with two parameters `page` and `place` . The rule above only rewrites URLs with one query perm `page` . If you need help with that please post a new question.

Comment: okay i have created new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69827605/url-rewrite-multiple-query