# URL Rewrite - Multiple query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to see how I can achieve the following rewrite rules.

From

```
https://localhost/site/?page=place&place=west
https://localhost/site/?page=location&location=cityname
```

To

```
https://localhost/site/place/west
https://localhost/site/location/city
```

I am able to change
https://localhost/site/?page=place to https://localhost/site/place but not with another additional query as mentioned above.

htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On
 #Redirect /site/?page=foobar to /site/foobar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /site/(?:index\.php)?\?page=(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /site/%1? [L,R]
# Internally rewrite new path to the original one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:site/)?(.+)/?$ /site/?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The above htaccess works for the following which is what I also need.

```
https://localhost/site/place
https://localhost/site/about
https://localhost/site/contact
```

Answer (score 4):

With your shown attempts, please try following htaccess rules file. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. New rules are clubbed to your already existing rules.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /site/
##New rules from here......
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/site/?\?page=([^&]*)&place=([^&]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /site/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# Internally rewrite new path to the original one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^site/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1&location=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Shouldn't `&place=` also follow the `([^&]*)` rule as there's no guarentee that this will be the final query string argument in the future

Comment: @Martin, that could be also used, but I have used all non-spaces capturing, because if a space comes that will end of THE_REQUEST variable's main part(which e need uri one).

Comment: But using "\S+" on `https://localhost/site/?page=place&place=west&home=yes` would mean %2 = "west&home=yes" ?

Comment: @Martin, yeah sure, I have edited my solution as per suggestion now. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I think it is semi-working.. The URL is display as https://localhost/site/place/west which is perfect but it is unable to display content. I am receiving this error. Warning: include_once(page/place/west.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [filepath]

Comment: @OneNation. Ok, so link https://localhost/site/place/west should be served by which file? Eg: index.php index.html etc?

Comment: should be served by index.php @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @OneNation, oh ok sure and do you want to send some parameters to index.php also? Like: `index.php?abc=def` etc?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes, Some of the parameters would be index.php?page=place&place=west and index.php?page=location&location=cityname

Comment: @OneNation, sure, could you please do check my edited code once and let me know if this helps you? Thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it didn't work :( I tried location/cityname - the include_once(page/location/cityname.php)  failed to open stream: No such file.

Comment: Let me try to give more information.. maybe it will help..
index.php?page=location --> gets data from page/location.php. Then
index.php?page=location&location=cityname --> gets data from the file of page/location.php , in location.php $_GET['location'] is used to get the cityname value. So with index.php?page=location&location=cityname, the $_GET['page'] is used to retrieve which file to use in 'page/' folder. The $_GET['location'] is used in location.php to query from DB where cityname=$_GET['location'] @RavinderSingh13

Comment: If URL is displayed as `https://localhost/site/one/two` then how it should be handled internally? It cannot be `index.php?page=one&location=two` and `index.php?page=one&place=two` at the same time.